# Clear session store for a specific user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the session_store cookie_store to save the sessions of my rails 4 application. Here my code

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session'

My question is how can I invalidate the session of a specific user?

Answer (score 1):

You can only invalidate the session of the current user - by calling `reset_session` which invalidates their session id.

The server has no idea which session ids are linked to what (database) user id with cookie_store. It just keeps track of a list of valid session identifiers. If the session identifier provided in the cookie is valid then Rails will unencrypt and deserialize the session storage cookie. This is where the user id is stored. Since the user ids are stored by the client there is no way to iterate through the session storages and find a session identifier from a user id.

If you want to keep tabs on the user sessions you need to use  different system such as using memcached or database session storage or access token grants.